# Extract dict from string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm calling a function that returns a string that contains a dict. How can I extract this dict keeping in mind that the first and last lines could contain '{' and '}'.

```
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"date": "10-09-2020"
}
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
```

I need to extract this value as a dict variable.

```
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"date": "10-09-2020"
}
```

Comment: Should the function be updated to return a proper dict?  (Essentially, solve data issues at the root, rather than writing additional code to deal with it.)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the function's output. I'm calling a shell command using subprocess and I expect the output to always be in that format.

Comment: Is the dict guaranteed to always be in the same location in the string?

Comment: So I need to extract the dict inside so that I can create a proper output, i.e removing certain key/values

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, there's always an unknown number of lines before and after it

Comment: Since your input can contain things with `{` and `}` characters, you will have to find each pair and see if it contains a valid dictionary (and hope there isn't something that just happens to look like something that would be a valid dictionary).

Comment: @MehdiKhlifi What does a *real* input file look like? Is the dict portion always written in exactly the same way? Does it contain embedded dicts and/or lists? Can string values inside the dict contain brackets and braces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

---

Taking on board comments from @martineau and @ekhumoro, the following edited code contains a function which searches through the string and extracts valid all `dict`s. This is a more robust approach to my previous answer as the contents of the real-world `dict` may vary, and this logic (hopes to) account for that.

#### Sample Code:

```
import json
import re

def extract_dict(s) -> list:
    """Extract all valid dicts from a string.
    
    Args:
        s (str): A string possibly containing dicts.
    
    Returns:
        A list containing all valid dicts.
    
    """
    results = []
    s_ = ' '.join(s.split('\n')).strip()
    exp = re.compile(r'(\{.*?\})')
    for i in exp.findall(s_):
        try:
            results.append(json.loads(i))        
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            pass    
    return results
```

#### Test String:

The OP's original string has been updated to add multiple `dict`s, a numeric value as a last field, and a `list` value.

```
s = """
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"date": 5
}
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"date": "2020-09-11"
}
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"dates": ["2020-09-11", "2020-09-12"]
}
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
"""
```

#### Output:

As the OP states, there is generally only one `dict` in the string, so this would (obviously) be accessed using `results[0]`.

```
>>> results = extract_dict(s)

[{'website': 'stackoverflow', 'type': 'question', 'date': 5},
 {'website': 'stackoverflow', 'type': 'question', 'date': '2020-09-11'},
 {'website': 'stackoverflow', 'type': 'question', 'dates': ['2020-09-11', '2020-09-12']}]
```

#### Original Answer:

---

Ignore this section. Although the code works, it fits the OP's request specifically and is not robust for other uses.

This sample uses regex to identify the dict start `{"` and dict end `"}` and extracting the middle, then converting the string to a proper `dict`.  As new lines get in the way and complicate the regex, I've just flattened the string to start.

Per a comment from @jizhihaoSAMA, I've updated to use `json.loads` to convert the string to a `dict`, as it's cleaner. If you don't want the additional import, `eval` will work as well, but not recommended.

#### Sample Code:

```
import json
import re

s = """
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
{"website": "stackoverflow",
"type": "question",
"date": "10-09-2020"
}
This is a {testing string} example
This {is} a testing {string} example
"""

s_ = ' '.join(s.split('\n')).strip()
d = json.loads(re.findall(r'(\{\".*\"\s?\})', s_)[0])

>>> d
>>> d['website']
```

#### Outputs:

```
{"website": "stackoverflow", "type": "question", "date": "10-09-2020"}

'stackoverflow'
```

Comment: `eval()` is not recommend, try to use more safer function like`ast.literal_eval()` or `json.loads`.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the OP's real input wil be as simple as the test example, so there's very little chance that this kind of approach will work in practice.

Comment: @ekhumoro - While this is a fair assumption in real-world, I feel the comment is unfair - as this view can be taken to nearly all answers on SO, and invalidate them.  This solution meets the OP's requirement and provided example. Anything beyond that is outside of scope.

Comment: That's not true at all. It's usually possible to generalise from test cases to take account of most real-world possibilities. If your solution can be invalidated by tiny changes to the input, it isn't really meeting the requirements in a useful way. (For example, your solution will break if the last value in the dict happens to be a number rather than a string).

Comment: @ekhumoro - Point well taken, and answer updated. Thanks for the expanded thinking.

Comment: Worked perfectly after removing `-> list` on line 3..