# Converting a string into List of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

I have a string represented as

```
'[{"Name": "Joe","LastName":"Doe","Classes:"[CS3302,CS3306,CS4469]"},{"Name": "Mathew","LastName":"Lee","Classes:"[CS3312,CS3301,CS4161]"}]'
```

How do I convert it to a list of dictionaries and read data from it?

Comment: `yourDicts = json.loads(yourString)`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850091/6340496) *might* be helpful to your case. It shows an example of how a string can be searched to extract multiple `dict`s and added to a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `json.loads()`

```
import json

str = '[{"Name": "Joe","LastName":"Doe","Classes":"[CS3302,CS3306,CS4469]"},{"Name": "Mathew","LastName":"Lee","Classes":"[CS3312,CS3301,CS4161]"}]'

output = json.loads(str)
```

Watch out, there is a quote missing after the "Classes" key